# BinaryReader / CSVReader rendering special characters as �

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, encoding

I start off in an MVC application, where I upload a CSV file through a view. This CSV file contains a special character. For this example I have a CSV file with just one field. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onhpt.png). As you can see this contains the special character (the umlaut) and saves fine in the CSV.

This file is uploaded through MVC and comes through as a parameter of type `HttpPostedFileBase` called `file`

This is processed using `BinaryReader` and its' bytes are read and saved into a database.

```
byte[] fileData;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
}
```

The end result of this is, for this example, the following string:

```
0x52FC676279
```

Later, when I wish to recreate the original string from the CSV file, I process the afformentioned string through a `CsvReader`:

```
var configuration = new CsvConfiguration { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

using (var stream = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(fileBytes)))
            {
                using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(stream, configuration))
                {
                    while (csvReader.Read())
                    {
                        // Do read stuff
                    }
                 }
             }
```

At this point I'm able to examine `csvReader > CurrentRecord` to view the decoded string. My problem is that special characters being decoded as � instead of their actual value. So, the value of `Rügby` which was in the original CSV file comes through as `R�gby`.

I'm assuming this is a matter of which encoding to use. I have changed the two `UTF-8` settings in the code above to various encodings to no avail.

Comment: what do you mean you've change them you've change them to use utf-8 you probably need to use utf-16 to support wide chars

Comment: Wrong character encoding?

Comment: You need to verify/know the encoding of the csv file. It doesn't seem to be UTF-8

Comment: You didn't specify the encoding for the `StreamReader`. And this is not how you're supposed to use `BinaryReader` - if you insist on reading the whole file as an arraay of bytes, just do a simple `Read`. `BinaryReader` is for structured binary formats, not for loading text files as bytes :)

Comment: Specifying Encoding on the StreamReader results in CSVReader giving a string array with a length of 1, and that single string being one large string of Chinese characters.

Comment: Your file is apparently encoded in Windows-1252. This is, unsurprisingly, a common occurrence on Windows systems, but simply reading it as if it's UTF-8 isn't going to work in that case. In general, you have to know in advance what encoding a file is using in order to make use of it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Am I not specifying the encoding in my BinaryReader when coverting the uploaded file to bytes?

Comment: The uploaded file is *already* in a particular encoding. You can try passing encodings to readers all you like, but that won't change anything about the actual bytes in the file. Specify the encoding as `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")` and you should see improvement. This leaves open the problem of how to detect the encoding (if you can't assume).